# Proper way of releasing an object in objective c

Tags: iphone, ipad, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

```
-(NSString *)returnString
{
      NSString *str=[NSString new];
       return str;
}

-(void)getString {
     NSString *string=[self returnString];
     [string release];
}
```

Is this an appropriate/correct way of releasing a `NSString`?

Also, if the lifetime of an autoreleased object is up at the end of a runloop. So can we drain a system generated autorelease pool manually? So that I can release all the autoreleased objects at the point i get a memory warning.

Comment: It's totally unclear to me what you're trying to do with your code snippet or what you're asking about it.  Why would you have a function that simply creates a new object and returns it uninitialized?

Comment: I am doing a huge project and in some parts of the project some objects are returning to the calling function without releasing it. So can i release it at the point where we are getting the string.

Answer (score 6):

You should create a object with autorelease function. 
Try this one

```
-(NSString *)returnString
   {
     NSString *str= [[NSString new] autorelease];
     return str;
   }
```

Comment: Ganesh is correct. Everytime you alloc a new object in memory but cannot explicitly release it because you have returned this object to another function or "someone" else now owns this object, you should always use autorelease.

Comment: You could consolidate the above into one line, but the basic premise is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely can drain the pool manually. Every time you drain a pool, you are indirectly sending `release` to all allocated objects in this pool.

Although keep in mind that you should only use `Autorelease` in some very specific situations. You shouldn't, for example, use it all the time to avoid worrying about releasing your objects manually.

Personally, I don't completely trust Autorelease, but when you give ownership of the object to "someone" else, it's your only option. For any other where you still own it and can release it manually, choose to do so.

Comment: i think if we are creating a nsautorelease pool we can drain it. But if we are not creating a autorelease pool all the autoreleased objects will get into to a system generated autorelease pool. And this pool will drain at the end of a run loop. My question is can we drain this pool manually.

Comment: Then I believe you can remove this object from the system's autorelease pool by simply sending `release` to this object. Thus not having to wait for the run loop to end to have it released.

Comment: That is not correct. Sending a `release` message to an object has no impact on what `autorelease` will do to it. If you do: `[[[[MyClass alloc] init] autorelease] release]`, your program will crash when the autorelease pool is drained and attempts to release an object that has already been destroyed.